# regex php email validation having .co.uk further

Tags: php, regex, email

the code is not running can anyone explain why ?

```
$string1 = "Dean_Johns123@cyber.net.uk";    //Example Email

$pattern = "/^[a-z][_][A-Z][_][0-9]*(@).[a-zA-Z]{2,9}[a-zA-Z]{2,3}.[a-zA-Z]{2}$/";

if(preg_match($pattern , $string1))
{
    echo " valid email";
}
else
{
    echo "not valid";
}
```

Comment: The code is running and works, but you use bad syntax.
About your regex you already answered. But if you are interested, you can look [http://emailregex.com/](http://emailregex.com/) and read
[https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 0):

The code is not running because the pattern you are using is wrong in syntax you can use 
`/^([a-z]*)([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)(@)([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*).([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*).([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)$/`
  You can visit https://regex101.com/ it explains every part of your regex to you.

Answer (score 0):

It would work it you right pattern like this

```
 $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(@)[a-zA-Z]{2,9}.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}.[a-zA-Z]{2}$/";
```

Demo : https://eval.in/850480